# UIScrollView isn't present on segue

Tags: uiscrollview, segue

I have issue with one segue between two ViewController's, when I try to log the `segue.destinationViewController.scrollView` it's NIL, in my case that is problem, because I need that scrollView to be available at this point. `-prepareForSegue:sender`.

The first code block is basic representation of my `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method. Second code block is the approach which i discovered to do what i want, but not in way which i want.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        viewController.questions = selectedIndexArray;
        NSLog(@"scrollView: %@", [viewController scrollView]); // this is logged as nil
}
```

-

However if I log the `scrollView` property from `-setQuestions:` method in the `ViewController` it's again NIL, until i do delayed execution:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"scrollView: %@", _scrollView); // returns object address and description
});
```

I don't like the `dispatch_after` approach, because that delay of 100 ms is noticeable and I will prefer to skip it.

So how to have `scrollView` property available in the beginning , back there in `prepareForSegue:sender:` ?

Comment: Is scrollView a public property of ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move my code for this example:

```
NSLog(@"scrollView: %@", _scrollView);
```

to `-viewDidLoad` method in `ViewController`